# FTL Boss impossible?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I beat the final boss in Faster Than Light?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81135/how-can-i-beat-the-final-boss-in-faster-than-light)

I have this ship:

[image]

To me it seems pretty impossible to win vs Flagship (it's the first flagship I have met) I have tried everything, but with my equipment I can't beat it.

Should I start over? (Of course I have a backup of my save file)

Note I am on Easy, but this is anything but easy. Without backing up my save, I would hardly have arrived at this stage.

Comment: have you tried the strategies in [this question yet](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81135/how-can-i-beat-the-final-boss-in-faster-than-light)?

Comment: and yea, your ship looks a bit underpowered to face the boss.  There's no harm restarting though, that's what this game is all about, you can't win every time.

Comment: Hm that's a bit boring... It took me quite some time to get at this point...

Comment: Yeah, the tricky part about this game is not so much reaching the last sector (though one doesn't always manage that) but reaching the last sector with a ship that has a chance against the flagship. :-) You'll know what to expect next time!

Comment: @SimonWaldman: you are right, but I feel I can't arrive with a better ship.. I have almost always killed every enemy ship and spent all scrap points =/

Comment: @yes123 the torus is surprisingly good at capturing ships as the transporter bay is right next to the medical bay.  Try going for that strategy next time.  You get more scraps etc when you capture.

Comment: I have won the final boss. But I didn't understand that it was the end of the game :D ... They should have made it impossible to win with this ship considering it is one of the first ship released

Comment: you should have a teleporter, this helps a lot with a boss (always take rockets down) and it is a good as done