# Hand-to-hand strategy for taking down the mothership

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I've been attempting to take ships by killing all their crew hand-to-hand, and was going to attempt the mothership in a similar way but I noticed they had what seemed like, a million doodz.

After barely scraping by the first stage, I got quickly polished off by a Rebel bomber.  I was wondering, if I kill a few of their guys, do they replenish between boss stages?

Comment: your question has been answered as a part of this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81135/how-can-i-beat-the-final-boss-in-faster-than-light

Comment: My bad, didn't search very thoroughly when I asked.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question on killing the crew: no the crew won't replenish, so once you kill them they will stay dead.  They will of course heal up if they get to the medibay. However there is a drawback to this, if you kill the human crew then the ship will become automated and becomes harder to kill, as it no longer needs humans for repairs / weapons etc.

Comment: Hmm, had not considered that last point.

Comment: Kill all but one, though, and the ship doesn't switch to automated (but is still crippled from lack of crew).  On easy and normal, that usually means leaving the crewmember in the laser room alive.  On hard... well, last playthrough I left the guy in the beam room alive, and just tolerated the boss becoming automated on stage 3 (it was still crippled on stage 2, which is the worst stage anyway).